# How to disable a button in React Native after clicking it

Tags: reactjs, button, react-native, native

I am doing a huge project and I am having some issues with it.

Every time I click the login button, it takes a while to make the database connection, and if this button is an alert and you click it multiple times, it will show the alert multiple times as well.

This is the button:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.submitButton}
              onPress={
                () => this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
              }>
              <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Login</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

I would like to disable the button after clicking it so the alert error only appears once.

This is where I want to put the code to deactivate the button:

```
if (respo == 'Wrong name or password.') {
          alert("Wrong Username and Password.");
        } else {
          if (respo.user.uid > 0) {
            if (Object.values(respo.user.roles).indexOf("student user") > -1) {
              AsyncStorage.setItem("u_uid", respo.user.uid);
              alert("Login Successfull.");
              Actions.home();
            } else {
              alert("Only Student user is allowed to login.");
            }
          }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use the `Button` component, which comes with a `disabled` prop?

Comment: Because it doesn't take the `styles` as a `prop`, and the `color prop` `renders` different views for both `android` and  `ios`.Kindly check the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the simplest logic could be:

1. Set up a variable that will track whether the the login process is in process, like
    `var loginInProcess = false`. This should probably be set in the state of some parent component that tracks the state of your application, but let's keep it simple.
2. In the `onPress` event, set the value `loginInProcess = true`
3. Execute the login actions conditionally, only if login is not in process:

For example:

```
   onPress = {() => {

    if (!loginInProcess) {
        loginInProcess = true;
        this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    } else {
        /*Login in process, do something else*/
    }}}>
```

4. If login fails *(your second block of code)*, reset the variable: `loginInProcess = false` to be able to try and "login" again.

Answer (score 2):

i have a good solution for this you can use this for disable the button

```
<View style={styles.MainContainer} >
     <TouchableOpacity
         activeOpacity = { .5 } 
         disabled={true}
         onPress={this.SampleButtonFunction} 
      > 
         <Text>Submit</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

this activeOpacity and disable is work for this